# Android Gallery starts between two views

Tags: android, view, gallery

I have an android application with a gallery that switches between textswitcher views. It always starts in between two textswitcher views. Why does this happen? I'm setting the selection to a specific position.

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        g.setAnimationDuration(200);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

```
    g.setAdapter(hello);
    g.setSpacing(20);
    g.setSelection(2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is an old question, I had the same problem and maybe it helps others. This was the crucial part of my Adapter:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Display display = ((WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_list_item, parent,false);
        view.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(width/3, Gallery.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

I wanted to have three items shown at the same time, so I took `parent.getWidth()/3`. however this led the gallery to start between two views. Getting the displays width shown in the upper code-sample worked fine for me